# Adding numbers and displaying a summary in c++

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char name[50];

    int page, prtotal, pagetot;

    int option;

    char answer;

    do {
        cout << "\n\nPlease enter your name: ";

        cin >> name;

        cout << "\n\nWelcome to Printworld " << name << endl;

        cout << "\n\nHow many pages would you like to print?  ";

        cin >> page;

        if (page <= 100)
        {
            cout << "\n\nThat will be " << page << "*$0.10=$" << 0.10 * page << endl;
            prtotal = 0.10 * page;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\nThat will be " << page << "*$0.05=$" << 0.05 * page << endl;
            prtotal = 0.05 * page;
        }

        // binding menu

        cout << "\n\nFor binding, which option would you like to select?\n" << endl;

        cout << "1) Hardcopy $50.50" << endl;
        cout << "2) Punch and Bind $40.50" << endl;
        cout << "3) Stitched Binding $25\n" << endl;
        cout << "4) No Binding $0\n" << endl;

        // Prompting user to enter an option according to menu
        cout << "Please select an option : ";

        cin >> option;

        if (option == 1) // Checking if user selected option 1
        {
            // Display hardcopy binding

            cout << "\nHardcopy $50.50+" << prtotal << "=$" << 50.50 + prtotal << endl;


        }
        else if (option == 2) // Checking if user selected option 2
        {
            // Displaying punch and bind
            cout << "\nPunch and Bind $40.50+$" << prtotal << "=$" << 40.50 + prtotal << endl;

        }
        else if (option == 3) // Checking if user selected option 3
        {
            // displaying stiched binding
            cout << "\nStitched Binding $25+$" << prtotal << "=$" << 25 + prtotal << endl;


        }
        else if (option == 4) // Checking if user selected option 4
        {
            // displaying no binding
            cout << "\nNo Binding $0+$" << prtotal << "=$" << 0 + prtotal << endl;

        }
        else // if user has entered invalid choice (other than 1,2,3 or 4)
        {
            // Displaying error message
            cout << "\nInvalid Option entered" << endl;
        }

        // bool to loop the process
        cout << "\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> answer;
        while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'y')
        {
            // error validation
            cout << "\nYou must enter (Y/N): ";

            cin >> answer;
        }
    } while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N');

    cout << "\nTotal Number: " << pagetot << endl;
}
```

This code is supposed to calculate the number of pages needed for printing and calculate the cost of printing and binding. At the end of the program, it is supposed to display a summary of all the transactions performed. For example, the total number of pages printed, the total cost of binding etc. I am having a hard time figuring out how to add all the pages in the loop and display them in the end. Also the same with the cost of binding. Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: you are not assigning any value to pagetot variable

Comment: The best help you can get at this stage, is to use a debugger, step through your program line by line, and watch how your variables change. If you did this, and noticed anything you can't explain, then come back and ask for such anomaly specifically.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're unfamiliar with debugger, you can use `std::cerr` to print some diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help. Note I am using double for prices.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[50];

    int page, pageSum = 0;
    double prtotal, prtotalSum = 0;

    int option;

    char answer;

    do {
        cout << "\n\nPlease enter your name: ";

        cin >> name;

        cout << "\n\nWelcome to Printworld " << name << endl;

        cout << "\n\nHow many pages would you like to print?  ";

        cin >> page;

        pageSum += page;

        if (page <= 100)
        {
            cout << "\n\nThat will be " << page << "*$0.10=$" << 0.10 * page << endl;
            prtotal = 0.10 * page;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\nThat will be " << page << "*$0.05=$" << 0.05 * page << endl;
            prtotal = 0.05 * page;
        }

        // binding menu

        cout << "\n\nFor binding, which option would you like to select?\n" << endl;

        cout << "1) Hardcopy $50.50" << endl;
        cout << "2) Punch and Bind $40.50" << endl;
        cout << "3) Stitched Binding $25\n" << endl;
        cout << "4) No Binding $0\n" << endl;

        // Prompting user to enter an option according to menu
        cout << "Please select an option : ";

        cin >> option;

        if (option == 1) // Checking if user selected option 1
        {
            // Display hardcopy binding

            cout << "\nHardcopy $50.50+" << prtotal << "=$" << 50.50 + prtotal << endl;
            prtotal += 50.50;


        }
        else if (option == 2) // Checking if user selected option 2
        {
            // Displaying punch and bind
            cout << "\nPunch and Bind $40.50+$" << prtotal << "=$" << 40.50 + prtotal << endl;
            prtotal += 40.50;

        }
        else if (option == 3) // Checking if user selected option 3
        {
            // displaying stiched binding
            cout << "\nStitched Binding $25+$" << prtotal << "=$" << 25 + prtotal << endl;
            prtotal += 25;


        }
        else if (option == 4) // Checking if user selected option 4
        {
            // displaying no binding
            cout << "\nNo Binding $0+$" << prtotal << "=$" << 0 + prtotal << endl;

        }
        else // if user has entered invalid choice (other than 1,2,3 or 4)
        {
            // Displaying error message
            cout << "\nInvalid Option entered" << endl;
        }

        prtotalSum += prtotal;

        // bool to loop the process
        cout << "\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> answer;
        while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'y')
        {
            // error validation
            cout << "\nYou must enter (Y/N): ";

            cin >> answer;
        }
    } while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N');

    cout << "\nTotal Pages: " << pageSum << endl;
    cout << "\nTotal Price: " << prtotalSum << endl;
}
```

Comment: The second task is to print the summary of transactions. It should be able to calculate and print the number of customer(s) served.

any idea how to do this part?

Comment: define int numCust = 0; and then increment it by one everytime you enter do while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any value to pagetot variable which you are trying to print at the end. Assign page value to this variable everytime user enters a val. Also intialize your variables to 0.

> ```
>   #include <iostream>
>   #include <stdio.h>
>
>   using namespace std;
>   int main(){
>
>
>     char name[50];
>     
>     int page, prtotal, pagetot=0;
>
>     int option;
>
>     char answer;
>
>
>     do
>     {
>
>
>           cout<<"\n\nPlease enter your name: ";
>
>           cin>>name;
>
>           cout<<"\n\nWelcome to Printworld "<<name<<endl;
>
>           cout<<"\n\nHow many pages would you like to print?  ";
>
>           cin>>page;
>           pagetot+=page;   // keep adding pages to this variable
>
>           if ( page <= 100 ) {               
>            cout<<"\n\nThat will be "<<page<<"*$0.10=$"<<0.10*page<<endl;
>            prtotal=0.10*page;
>
>           }
>            else {          
>            cout<<"\n\nThat will be "<<page<<"*$0.05=$"<<0.05*page<<endl;  
>            prtotal=0.05*page; 
>
>            }
>
>         //binding menu
>
>           cout<<"\n\nFor binding, which option would you like to select?\n"<<endl;
>
>           cout <<"1) Hardcopy $50.50"<< endl;
>           cout <<"2) Punch and Bind $40.50"<< endl;
>           cout <<"3) Stitched Binding $25\n"<< endl;
>           cout <<"4) No Binding $0\n"<< endl;
>
>                //Prompting user to enter an option according to menu
>           cout << "Please select an option : ";
>
>           cin >>option;
>
>            if(option == 1) // Checking if user selected option 1
>            {
>                  //Display hardcopy binding
>
>                 cout << "\nHardcopy $50.50+"<<prtotal<<"=$"<<50.50+prtotal<<endl;
>
>
>             }
>              else if(option == 2) // Checking if user selected option 2
>              {
>                //Displaying punch and bind 
>               cout << "\nPunch and Bind $40.50+$"<<prtotal<<"=$"<<40.50+prtotal<<endl;
>
>             }
>              else if(option == 3) // Checking if user selected option 3
>              {
>                //displaying stiched binding
>               cout << "\nStitched Binding $25+$"<<prtotal<<"=$"<<25+prtotal<<endl;
>
>
>               }
>             else if(option == 4) // Checking if user selected option 4
>             {
>                //displaying no binding
>               cout << "\nNo Binding $0+$"<<prtotal<<"=$"<<0+prtotal<< endl;
>
>             }
>              else //if user has entered invalid choice (other than 1,2,3 or 4)
>              {
>                //Displaying error message
>                cout << "\nInvalid Option entered" << endl;
>              }
>
>
>              //bool to loop the process
>              cout << "\nDo you want to try again? (Y/N) " ;
>              cin >> answer ;
>              while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N' && answer != 'Y' && answer != 'y')
>              {
>          //error validation
>               cout << "\nYou must enter (Y/N): ";
>
>               cin >> answer;
>              }
>
>     }while (answer != 'n' && answer != 'N');
>
>     cout << "\nTotal Number of pages: "<<pagetot<<endl;
>
>   }
> ```

Comment: Hooray! The world's fastest human online compiler, has found the bug.

Answer (score 0):

initialize the pagetot to zero(0)
and when you input page just add the page to the pagetot.
see the line 26 of the this program given in the link

```
http://ideone.com/HU899j
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks guys...i managed to figure it out :D